# How to plot a bar graph from pandas dataframe using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on facebook recruitment Human or bot dataset.

```
bids_train.groupby(['outcome','merchandise'])['bid_id'].count()
```

[image: This is the pandas series I want to plot]

I know how to do it using seaborn but can't seem to figure out how to plot it using matplotlib. Just a little help will do.

Answer (score 0):

**first, lets put your dataframe in a variable**

```
df = bids_train.groupby(['outcome','merchandise'])['bid_id'].count()
```

now, there's a shortcut to using matplotlib from a dataframe without seaborn , so this should work

```
df.plot.bar()
```

if you want to write your own matplotlib code, here's a sample based on the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ind = range(len(df.index))
plt.bar(ind, df.values)
plt.xticks(ind, df.index, rotation='vertical')
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work. But I was wondering if I can plot it with 'outcome' as the hue. I checked the matplotlib documentation and I didn't found anything related to that. They all lead to seaborn in someway.

Comment: @SuryaK seaborn does save you a lot of trouble writing complex matplotlib code. whats the issue with using seaborn?

Comment: There's no issue, I was just curious.